# jQuery if anyone understand this URL please explain me

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am using jQuery bind, detach, etc. and I found this [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1998-Using-jQuery-To-Bind-And-Trigger-Event-Handlers-On-Detached-DOM-Nodes.htm).

Please anyone explain in detail about this.

Comment: -1 Probably not. I doubt anyone wants to spoon feed you.

Comment: @Byron im just wanna get the technology breadth and deep hope you guys will sure make that happen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you how to bind and trigger event handlers on detached nodes outside the DOM. It also tells you that if you attach the node to the DOM then the event handlers are removed.